# Visiting admin brings up the installer

Tags: admin, migration

I recently moved a Craft 2 install from a server running PHP 5.x to one running PHP 7.x. All seems to be well. The custom "system offline" message appears as expected when visiting the home page, anyway. It also appears when visiting a random URL.

But when visiting the admin URL I'm redirected to the installer. I'd obviously rather not do this as the system and DB are already there.

Do I have any options here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like it's viewing the DB as being empty. The access credentials are correct (it's technically connecting to the database), but **it's not seeing any tables in the database.**

1. Does your site use a prefix (ie: `craft_`) before the database tables? Check to make sure that the prefix specified in `config/db.php` matches the actual table prefixes.
2. Double-check to make sure you're connecting to the *right* database.